# ASP Classic with SQL - No value given for one or more parameters

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am receiving this error message but can not see the problem, anyone spot it?

No value given for one or more required parameters.

```
set postRs=server.CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
readsql = "UPDATE [post] SET pos_content=bob WHERE pos_ID = 136"
postRs.Open readsql, conx, adOpenKeyset, AdLockOptimistic
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around strings

```
readsql = "UPDATE [post] SET pos_content = 'bob' WHERE pos_ID = 136"
                              here---------^---^
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry if the question was obvious, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Put ' for string value

```
readsql = "UPDATE [post] SET pos_content='bob' WHERE pos_ID = 136"
```